# Can we merge the tables having same schema while using eloquent relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tables namely attendance_2022_2023 , attendance_2021_2022, attendance_session with the following schema (DB is MySQL)

```
attendance_session:
id
subject_id

attendance_2021_2022 (Attendance model)
id
attendance_session_id
student_id
attendance_status

attendance_2022_2023 (AttendanceNewYear Model)
id
attendance_session_id
student_id
attendance_status
```

the following relations are added in the attendance_session model:

```
public function list_members_1() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Attendance','attendance_session_id');
}

public function list_members_2() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Model\AttendanceNewYear','attendance_session_id');
}
```

previously there was a single table and with the addition of the new table, I want to know if it is possible to merge these relations together. something like

```
public function list_members() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Attendance','attendance_session_id')->orhasMany('App\Model\AttendanceNewYear','attendance_session_id');
}
```

the reason that I wanted this to work is that there are may places in the code where we used the following code which is becoming troublesome with the merge:

```
AttendanceSession::whereIn('id', $some_range)->with('list_members');
```

Comment: Looks like you should just have one Attendance model and table. Add a year column and it will become much simpler when you end up with more years

Comment: but the problem with that there are nearly half a million records every year and most of the time, records in the previous year are not being queried a lot which just makes the queries a lot slower. considering that we have a data for nearly 6 years and the future data which might add up to an increasing number of records, we decided to split the tables

Comment: Is $some_range the ids you know belong to a specific year? You could also do a union query when you need to search all the tables in the way you seem to want. Indexing should help but I suspect you already did that.

Comment: the ids depend on the query proposed by the client. this design was made to support normal academic years which end in may where a new table will be started. But if client wants to view the attendance data for a random range (like the data from sep 2021 to sep 2022) they should be able to. and yes, we did index the table

Comment: Adding a new model and table each year seems counter intuitive for me but ok I see your issue. How about for the queries that do need to search the different tables you do unions? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#unions

Comment: Even with millions of records, querying should not be a problem with proper indexing. For eg: you can have a column `academic_year` (which can have values like 2021-2022 or 2022-2023) on the (single) `attendance` table and create an index on that column. Then on `AttendanceSession` model having single `hasMany` relationship `attendance` should suffice.

Comment: Creating a new table and a new model every year not only seems like a code smell but will pose bigger problems with regards to code maintainability and scaling. If you have really huge data like billions of records generated every year than switching to something like SingleStore db would be better choice.